# Select from table with additional predefined records not existing in database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to Select rows from table in database with addition of predefined rows not existing in database?

```
SELECT Name 
FROM [dbo].[TableFoo] -> returns Names (Name1, Name2, Name3)
```

I want it to additionally return predefined value 'NameNotInDatabase':

```
SELECT Name 
FROM [dbo].[TableFoo] + some tsql -> returns Names (Name1, Name2, Name3, NameNotInDatabase)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `UNION ALL`?

```
SELECT Name
FROM [dbo].[TableFoo]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NameNotInDatabase';
```

Comment: Perfect - just what I needed.